# Java Synchrinization

Tags: java, multithreading, list, synchronization, event-dispatch-thread

1. An object has two synchronized list attributes (listA and listB) and a method called add(...) which adds an element into these two lists. My question is: should this method be synchronized if it is called from differnt threads?
2. can problems occur when the method SwingUtilities.invokeLater is used inside synchronozed methods?
3. when using synchronized(this){..code...}, is in this case only the code-block or all methods of the object (this) blocked when a thread access the code-block?

Comment: `An object has two synchronized list attributes`. Attributes cannot be synchronized in Java.

Comment: I mean: private List<String> listA = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
 private List<String> listB = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

Answer (score 0):

Actually synchronized methods are the same as synchronized(this){} because "this" refers to the object and this one will provide the lock. If you use any of these synchronizations and one thread calls a synchronized method, the other threads cannot access all synchronized methods of the object. if you want to avoid this, create a new variable to provide the lock instead of synchronizing the method. For instance

```
  public void add(String s)
  {
       private Object block = new Object();
        synchronized(block)
       {
           listA.add(s);
            listB.add(s);
       }

   }

  public int count()
  {
        return listA.size();  //returns the most recent listA update size
                               // method can be accessed while another thread adds elements to listA
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > An object has two synchronized list attributes (listA and listB) and a
   >   method called add(...) which adds an element into these two lists. My
   >   question is: should this method be synchronized if it is called from
   >   differnt threads?

That depends. If you want the order of the elements in listA and listB to be the same, then yes, you should synchronize when you're adding to both lists. Otherwise, if would be possible that you get things in this order:

- Thread A adds element to listA
- Thread B adds element to listA
- Thread B adds element to listB
- Thread A adds element to listB

-

2. > can problems occur when the method SwingUtilities.invokeLater is used
   >   inside synchronozed methods?

No, there's no problem with that. I don't really see what problem you think that you could get.

3. > when using synchronized(this){..code...}, is in this case only the
   >   code-block or all methods of the object (this) blocked when a thread
   >   access the code-block?

It blocks all non-static methods that are synchronized (because that means the same as `synchronized (this)` and all code blocks that use `synchronized (this)`. 
In addition, it blocks any code in other classes that synchronizes on the same object.
Static methods and non-synchronized methods do not block while you are inside `synchronized (this)`.

Comment: thank you, can you please explain me what is the difference of synchronization a static method and synchronization a non-static method?